# In what way is this answer NOT duplicate?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, duplicate-answers

I recently came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27941648/1714410). Looking closely I noticed it is the same as [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20758210/1714410).
Therefore, I down-voted it, voted to delete it and flagged it as a duplicate answer.
I was very surprised to see my flag was declined

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

"No  evidence"? Come on! the flagged answer adds no new information - it is exactly the same as the original one.

Why was my flag declined?

Comment: You reference the same post?!

Comment: In my opinion the answer that you flagged is better than other one. Both of them without any explaination, but that answer is shorter.

Comment: @juergend I referenced two **different** answers to the same question (in the same thread)

Comment: @sacma I agree that in general shorter code=better, but when no explanation is added and the code is not super-clear, then shorter=worse. Moreover, it looks like the user just copied the older answer made very little change (insignificant) and posted as an answer. I strongly feel this is **not** the kind of behavior we want to see on SO.

Comment: @Shai Since I signed up, I see lots of bad behaviors in SO, this one looks like a little puppy if we compare them.

Comment: @sacma okay. but once someone flagged such a mis-behavior (minor as it is) shouldn't moderator at least not decline this flag? It is one thing to ignore such behavior, and completely other encourage it by declining this flag.

Comment: @Shai: so someone thought of a more compact approach and posted that as an answer. **That is behaviour is not wrong or inappropriate**. You get that with code all the time.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not familiar with matlab, and to me the answers look **very different**. The newer post may be low-quality, but it is **not a duplicate answer**. They may have rehashed the approach, but they never copied code wholesale. I would have declined your flag as well, if I were a moderator.

You'll need to come up with much clearer evidence that any plagiarism is going on here. Until such time, downvote or comment, and move on.

Comment: "...if I were a moderator..." At some point, we'll have to fix that.

Comment: @Yannis Only if he makes the same promise I had to, though!

Comment: @Yannis Well I guess this just got fixed!